# Is this possible, LWJGL MovingObjects

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, lwjgl

I have looked up how to more things in **OpenGL / LWJGL**. I mean this having an object move relative to the player. Most tutorials tell me that I should use **glTranslate** and **display lists**, but I would prefer to do something like what is below:

```
int y = 0;

while (true){
   y++;

   glBegin(GL_QUADS);
       glVertex3f(-1, y, 1);
       glVertex3f(-1, y, -1);
       glVertex3f(1, y, -1);
       glVertex3f(1, y, 1);
   glEnd();    
}
```

I know this doesn't work, but I am wondering if there is a similar way to do it that does not involve **display lists**. If there isn't thats fine, but if there it that would be great!

Comment: These functions are deprecated, and although they are easy to learn, they will not be around for too much longer. I highly recommend learning how to use vertex buffer objects to draw - you put all four vertices in a buffer, and draw it all at once.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an object to move relative to the player, then just don't translate it. This is how a sky-box is normally implemented - you create a rotation matrix from the player's direction, but don't create the translation matrix.